# Could someone please tell me what I am doing wrong with jQuery.get() in the javascript function saturday()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, highcharts

Could someone please tell me what I am doing wrong with `jQuery.get()` in the javascript function `saturday()`? The javascript code I wrote so far is shown below.

my index.html

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>jVectorMap demo</title> 
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-jvectormap-1.1.1.css"
type="text/css" media="screen"/>
 <script src="jquery.js"></script>
 <script src="jquery-jvectormap-1.1.1.min.js"></script>
 <script src="us-aea-en.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

function saturday () {
jQuery.get("coordinates.json", function(data){ 
   alert(data);
});
}   



</script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="USA-map" style="width: 1200px; height: 800px"></div>
  <script language="javascript">
    function processOrder() {
       var pluginContainer = $("#USA-map");
       pluginContainer.vectorMap(
       {
           map: 'us_aea_en',
           onRegionOver: function(event, code){
               pluginContainer.saturday();
           }
       }
     );
  }
   </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="foo.js"></script>

<script src="highcharts.js"></script>

<script src="../../js/modules/exporting.js">
</script>


<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>


</body>
</html>
```

foo.js

```
processOrder();
```

Comment: `pluginContainer.saturday();` ??? Did you mean `saturday();`? Because I don't see anywhere else you're calling the `saturday` function.

Comment: Asking what you're doing wrong isn't really a good question. You're supposed to debug your code, isolate the problem, explain what you tried to solve it and post a demo to reproduce the issue if possible. Then people might help you out.

Comment: Try [`.getJSON()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/). Might be better suited for your use case...

Comment: What is expected & what is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
pluginContainer.saturday();
```

You should just do:

```
saturday();
```

because `saturday()` is a global function.

Also `jQuery.getJSON` could be a better choice than `jQuery.get` as your resource is in JSON format. http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/

Cheers

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am about to accept  it.

Comment: Welcome. I added a little more info

Answer (score 0):

1) `saturday` is a global function, not a method of `pluginContainer` object, so you should call it this way:

```
saturday();
```

or:

```
window.saturday()
```

2) 'coordinates.json' is a resource returning data in JSON format, right? Please try `jQuery.getJSON` instead of `jQuery.get` (if you want jQuery to handle JSON for you).
But keep in mind that 'coordinates.json' will request to the resource relatively from your current location. So if, let's say, your URL looks like this `http:// mysite.com/some/path/index.html`, then browser will send request to `http:// mysite.com/some/path/coordinates.json`